# Common use of apps in Django

Tags: python, django

Quick question;

I am starting to develop a new order / invoicing project in Django. The project will initially require the following features;

1. Login page
2. Add new customer form
3. Add new product form
4. Create Order form (select one customer and then multiple products / quantities)
5. Promote Order to Invoice
6. Overviews for Customers, Products, Orders and Invoices in Tables
7. Export Orders and Invoices to PDF

To get a good start i was wondering what the best practice is, creating separate apps for all above "Screens" or combine them in one app?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, an app is a business component. Dont think of each functionality as a separate app. Example: Order is an app, that interacts with the customer app,  Or if you want to have the whole thing in a "procurement" app, and all components within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation is use an app for each component, think in django apps like modules. The Orders app, Products app... separate your bussiness logic in apps is very useful for reuse code in the future.